# Arduino SD card and Excel file

Tags: arduino, android-sdcard

I have an Arduino SD card, it saves the data from IMU sensor into a text file. Is that possible to let the SD card saves this data into an excel file directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to know the binary format of an excel file for this. You can however, create the file as a `*.csv`, or a simple `*.txt` file.

For each column, separate data with a comma. And Separate each row with a new line.

In Excel you can import the text file and specify how it is delimited. However if you use a csv file, you can simply 'open with' excel (or associate the extension with excel) and it will open the data automatically.

If you run python on your PC (or can), there is a nice script here witch can bulk convert the csv files to excel workbooks: https://superuser.com/a/301451/461279

Comment: Voting up, @Chris! It makes no sense to write an excel binary file on Arduino, current xlsx also needs zip. CSV is the way to go.